# Angular2 HashLocationStratery failes in IE11 and Safari reload takes to default route

Tags: angular

When you use hashlocationstrategy in angular2 its working fine with chrome and firefox. Wherein ie 11 and safari browsers reload doesn't propagate hash locations. So its redirecting to default route

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: browser skips hash locations in ie11 and safari browsers

Comment: What version are you using? Can you post examples of your code and can you replicate this in a plunker? Here's a blank Angular2 plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5 Add examples of your code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Edge browser using HashLocationStrategy with Angular 5.